# Replacing strings using regex using Pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, replace

In Pandas, why does the following not replace any strings containing an exclamation mark with whatever follows it?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: ser = pd.Series(['Aland Islands !Åland Islands', 'Reunion !Réunion', 'Zi
   ...: mbabwe'])

In [3]: ser
Out[3]: 
0    Aland Islands !Åland Islands
1                Reunion !Réunion
2                        Zimbabwe
dtype: object

In [4]: patt = r'.*!(.*)'

In [5]: repl = lambda m: m.group(1)

In [6]: ser.replace(patt, repl)
Out[6]: 
0    Aland Islands !Åland Islands
1                Reunion !Réunion
2                        Zimbabwe
dtype: object
```

Whereas the direct reference to the matched substring does work:

```
In [7]: ser.replace({patt: r'\1'}, regex=True)
Out[7]: 
0    Åland Islands
1          Réunion
2         Zimbabwe
dtype: object
```

What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: I think you are missing `regex=True` in first statement.

Comment: `import re` and use `ser.apply(lambda row: re.sub(patt, repl, row))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
pattern = r'(.*)!'
ser.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
```

In your case, you didn't set `regex=True`, as it is false by default.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `replace` does not support a method as a replacement argument. Thus, all you can do is to import `re` library implicitly and use `apply`:

```
>>> import re
>>> #... your code ...
>>> ser.apply(lambda row: re.sub(patt, repl, row))
0    Åland Islands
1          Réunion
2        Zimbabwe"
dtype: object
```

Comment: Turns out that (as of Pandas 0.22) `Series.str.replace` does accept a callable, but `Series.replace` doesn't.

Comment: @xnx Your question was about how to replace all values in a data frame. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `replace` methods in Pandas.

The one that acts directly on a Series can take a regex pattern string or a compiled regex and can act in-place, but *doesn't allow the replacement argument to be a callable*. You must set `regex=True` and use raw strings.

With:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(['Aland Islands !Åland Islands', 'Reunion !Réunion', 'Zimbabwe'])
```

Yes:

```
ser.replace(r'.*!(.*)', r'\1', regex=True, inplace=True)
ser.replace(r'.*!', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
regex = re.compile(r'.*!(.*)', inplace=True)
ser.replace(regex, r'\1', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

No:

```
repl = lambda m: m.group(1)
ser.replace(regex, repl, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

There's another, used as `Series.str.replace`. This one accepts a callable replacement but won't substitute in-place and doesn't take a `regex` argument (though regular expression pattern strings can be used):

Yes:

```
ser.str.replace(r'.*!', '')
ser.str.replace(r'.*!(.*)', r'\1')
ser.str.replace(regex, repl)
```

No:

```
ser.str.replace(regex, r'\1')
ser.str.replace(r'.*!', '', inplace=True)
```

I hope this is helpful to someone out there.